# Wordpress site moved to new server, permalinks work but homepage redirects and creates a WP 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I apologise if this has been asked, I was unable to find clear information anywhere on it.

We've recently been forced into moving to a VPS hosting package.

Thewre were a few issues with links that I managed to fix but now the issue lies with the home page. Every page apart from the home page works as should and at the correct address. I.e. website.co.uk/contact instead of /blog/contact.

I assume this has either something to do with the .htaccess file and/or mod rewrite being disabled on the new server.

Most solutions I`ve found all relate to the homepage working and the other pages not. I'm having basically the opposite of this problem.

See http://www.crowdwifi.co.uk it redirects to the /blog/ and creates the 404 Error within Wordpress. You can see from there the other pages and permalinks are fine.

Im on tablet at the moment but can post htaccess code for the root in here in an hour if it helps. I contacted host support but theyve been rather slow so I figure it may be easier for me to try and resolve it.

Added the .htaccess from the "/blog/" subdirectory below.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post up a copy of your .htaccess file?

EDIT:

Set both WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) to **http://www.crowdwifi.co.uk** if that doesn't work then try changing your htaccess to this as well:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: You should use the comment section to question to OP instead of Answer section.

Comment: Certainly Stephen,  I'll post it when im home in about 1hour. Is it the htaccess file within the root folder or the one within the subdirectory (/blog/ where all the WP files are hosted)?

Comment: Sorry guys, first time posting. It should be in your wordpress root where you would find the wp-logs, wp-content, wp-include etc... folders

Comment: Thats fine I'll add that shortly. I have a copy of it in the root folder too as to remove the /blog/ extension. I'll add the WP folder one though.

Comment: Set the post's page to be the news page in the **reading settings**

Comment: Ok, I tried setting both wordpress and site url as crowdwifi.co.uk again but it broke the site again. It basically removes css and admin panel, to fix it I then need to update functions.php. So I've got it back working and I've made the other edits, news page is now linked to the posts page for reading. Still no such luck. The reason www.crowdwifi.co.uk/blog is the wordpress URL is because that is the directory in which wordpress is installed for it, if you follow.

I appreciate your help so far.

Comment: maybe this is the answer? http://www.site5.com/blog/apache/htaccess/redirect-to-blog/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your Front page settings are not pointing to a specific page?

- Dashboard => Settings => Reading => A static page (select below) => **Front page**

Have you also checked your General Settings do not have the wrong URL?

- Dashboard => Settings => General => **WordPress Address (URL)**
- Dashboard => Settings => General => **Site Address (URL)**

Comment: I wasn't aware of the reading settings but I just checked them and that's fine. The site was running perfectly prior to the server switch and reupload.

General settings. Wordpress Address is down as "http://www.crowdwifi.co.uk/blog"
Site Address as "http://www.crowdwifi.co.uk" 
So they all seem right.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand but should your wordpress address not be: http://www.crowdwifi.co.uk also?

Comment: Dashboard => Settings => Reading => Posts page. Here you should select /blog/

Comment: All the wordpress file are hosted at crowdwifi.co.uk/blog/ so I assumed this  should be the wordpress url. I made both of them crowdwifi.co.uk briefly earlier and it broke the site aha.

Comment: and in regards to the posts page there's no option for /blog/ on the drop down. I can set it to the home which is listed as "welcome to crowd" but it then says the 2 urls in reading settings should not be the same. All posts are on the news page too, not the home, if that makes a difference.